# What's the correct way of writing the hasNext() function in C?

Tags: c, list, null

I'm working with lists and I'm a bit confused as to how hasNext() works.
I thought it'd be like this:

```
int hasNext(const listADT list) {    
   return list->current->tail!= NULL;
}
```

But I've seen it written like this:

```
int hasNext(const listADT list) {    
  return list->current != NULL;
}
```

I'm not sure which one is correct. I thought that the last element was supposed to point to NULL. If that's not the case and the second version is correct, does that mean that NULL is counted as the last element of the list?

EDIT: I'm trying to write a listADT to work with lists in general, there's not a specific thing I'm trying to do other than have a function that returns 1 if the current node has a next node.

Here's the list's struct:

```
typedef struct listCDT {
   struct node * first;
   size_t size;
   node * current;
 } listCDT;
```

And the node's:

```
typedef struct node {
     elemType elem;
     struct node * tail;
  } node;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In a list that is not circular, the last element should point to `NULL`.

Comment: Not possible to tell without knowing your actual list structure and how the node fields are intended to be used.

Comment: If `list->current` is `NULL`, `list->current->tail` would attempt to dereference `NULL`.

Comment: Neither function make much sense. On a linked list you usually hold a reference to the `first` element, also called `head`, and each element holds a reference to the  `next` element, and the last element has it's `next` attribute set to `NULL`, indicating there's no next element. The list doesn't hold a reference to the "current" element, that's something only your iterator should know, so you're not supposed to pass the `list` to a function and expect it to factor the `current` element out of it, of course you can design it to be like that but it doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @lurker I'm not sure if it has a specific name, it's a linked list that has pointers to the first and current node and each node has an element and a pointer to another node (tail).

Comment: @Dan The question shall be closed because it does not make sense without provided list definition.

Comment: @fiddlingbits my question is, if current points to the node that has its tail pointing to NULL. What would hasNext return? Because list->current is not pointing to NULL

Comment: `tail` is an odd name for `next` pointer if that's what it really means. If that's the case, then the first function is the obvious choice (but with a NULL check for `list->current` added).

Comment: if `listADT` is a struct (why you are passing it and not a pointer to it is odd), but you would want `int hasNext(const listADT list) { return list.current->tail!= NULL; }`. if `tail` is the `head` node in the `current` list. Please provide [A Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example (MCVE)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @davidC.Rankin listADT is the pointer to the struct listCDT (I'm using Abstract Data Types). The list has a first pointer and a current pointer. hasNext gets a pointer to a list and if the node pointed by current is pointing to another node, hasNext should return 1.

Comment: So you are saying with `typedef struct listCDT { ... } listCDT;` you have somewhere `typedef listCDT* listADT;` In that case, you would use the `->` operator instead of the `.` operator. You will want to review: [Is it a good idea to **typedef** pointers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750178/is-it-a-good-idea-to-typedef-pointers).

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you're trying to do...

---

This function could be called before attempting to advance some variable to the next item, in order to prevent  NULL references

```
int hasNext(const listADT list) {    
   return list->current->tail!= NULL;
}
```

---

This function could be called after you've advanced in your list, if you're not concerned in the first place about avoiding a NULL reference

```
int hasNext(const listADT list) {    
  return list->current != NULL;
}
```